# OQL syntax for counting objects matching criteria

Tags: java, hprof, oql, eclipse-mat

how can I count objects in Eclipse MAT using OQL syntax?
This doesn't work :

```
SELECT count(a) FROM org.hibernate.engine.EntityEntry a 
WHERE (toString(a.entityName)="my.pojo")
```

*(I want to count the number of hibernate pojos loaded into memory)*

There must be a very quick way to do so...Thanks for helping me out !

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT toString(entry.entityName) FROM org.hibernate.engine.EntityEntry entry WHERE (toString(entry.entityName) = "My.Pojo")
```

In the result, count will show up as `Total:X of Y entries.` The value you are interested in is `Y`.